# removing non English words from df.columns

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am appending multiple datasets together, unfortunately in the data collection some data collectors added the translation to the English question.

df['What is your name'] is reported in other datasets as df['What is your name Como te llamas']

Ideally, I would only want df['What is your name']

This is true for the name column as for many other columns (age, housing etc. etc.).

I am using nltk to get rid of all non-English word in the column names using the following code:

```
df_t.columns = " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(df_t.columns) 
    if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
```

But I get the following mistake error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-65a4c079ba1a> in <module>()
     34     df_t['File Name'] = df_t['File Name'].str.strip().str[-30:]
     35     df_t.columns = df_t.columns.str.replace(r'(^.*female.*$)', 'n_female_workers')
---> 36     df_t.columns = " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(df_t.columns) if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
     37 
     38     list_month.append(df_t)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\regexp.py in tokenize(self, text)
    129         # If our regexp matches tokens, use re.findall:
    130         else:
--> 131             return self._regexp.findall(text)
    132 
    133     def span_tokenize(self, text):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How to solve it?

Comment: `nltk.wordpunct_tokenize` requires a `str` object as the argument, you are passing it a `pd.Series`

Comment: yes, i felt that was the case, would you know how to correct the code?

Comment: jezrael it returns the same mistake unfortunately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need loop by columns names for pass scalar `string` to `wordpunct_tokenize` function:

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame(columns=['What is your name Como te llamas'])

words = ['what','is','your','name']
df_t.columns = [" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(x) 
                       if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha()) 
                       for x in df_t.columns]
print (df_t)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [What is your name]
Index: []
```